# Update query error: the multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to update a column by setting its value from another table based on a condition. So I did the following :-

```
UPDATE 
    [dbo].MachineLog
SET 
    A.EmployeeId = B.EmployeeId 
FROM
    [dbo].MachineLog as A
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].DeviceCode as B ON A.DeviceEnrollNo = B.DeviceEnrollNo
WHERE
    A.EmployeeId = 0 AND B.EmployeeId <> 0
```

I am getting the error :

> The multi-part identifier "A.EmployeeId" could not be bound.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the alias from the `set` clause, and change the table target to the alias.
I'm not sure exactly why it's impossible to use the alias from the `from` clause in the `set` clause, but it is possible to use it in the `update` clause.
Perhaps someone else can shed some light on the reason why is that so.

```
UPDATE 
    A
SET 
    EmployeeId = B.EmployeeId   
FROM
    [dbo].MachineLog as A
    INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].DeviceCode as B
    ON A.DeviceEnrollNo = B.DeviceEnrollNo
WHERE
    A.EmployeeId = 0 AND B.EmployeeId <> 0
```

Comment: If people are to learn, it's helpful to point out a) What you've changed and b) **Why** it fixes the problem.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Correct. edited my answer.